# Python discord bot message defined problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to build a bot that detects a specific emoji. When bot gets this, it's moving message to specific channel. For example, if message reaction has "like_emoji", it has to move this message.content to "xxx" channel. I couldn't find any solution on stackoverflow (or maybe I didn't search deeper).

Here is my code:

```
import os
import sys
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

my_secret = os.environ['locksecret']

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents = discord.Intents(messages=True,guilds=True,reactions=True,members=True,presences=True)

Bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "!",intents=intents)
@Bot.event
async def on_reaction_add(reaction,user):
  channel = reaction.message.channel
  await channel.send("emoji added")
  if reaction.emoji == '':
    channel = Bot.get_channel("channel_id")
    await channel.send("{} written by:\n {}".format(message.author.mention,message.content))
    await message.channel.send("{} your message move to this channel --> {}".format(message.author.mention,channel.mention))
    await message.add_reaction("✔️")
Bot.run(my_secret)
```

When I do this, I get this error:

```
***Ignoring exception in on_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 57, in on_reaction_add
    await channel.send("{} written by:\n {}".format(message.author.mention,message.content))
NameError: name 'message' is not defined***
```

How can I solve this problem?
By the way, in code spaces, there is some code that I tried to bot command, because of this, console says "line 57"

Comment: The error tells you what the problem is? You are using `message.author.mention, message.content` and `message.channel.send` but `message` is not defined in any way.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `message` is no where defined, just like your error states. The [`on_reaction_add` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_reaction_add) doesn't provide the message that got the reaction added. You should use the [`on_raw_reaction_add` event](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_raw_reaction_add) instead.

---

```
@Bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    guild = Bot.get_guild(<your-guild-id>)
    channel = guild.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
    await channel.send("emoji added")
    if payload.emoji.name == '':
      await channel.send("{} written by:\n {}".format(message.author.mention,message.content))
      await message.channel.send("{} your message move to this channel --> {}".format(message.author.mention,channel.mention))
      await message.add_reaction("✔️")
```

Comment: guild = Bot.get_guild(<your-guild-id>)
that part you mean bot user id or mine?

Comment: The guild id. If you don't want it to be static use `payload.guild_id` like so:

`guild = Bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)`

Comment: oh thx. it had been fixed. but there is another problem became. it sending message same channel. how can i choose the channel?

Comment: Then send it in the desired channel with `await guild.get_channel(<channel-id>).send("...")` where <channel-id> has to be replaced with the actual channel-id. If it doesn't work right away, maybe ask another question regarding this.

Comment: oh really thank you sir. last question. how can i get count of "emoji"? for example if n times get "emoji" then do bla bla. do i have to make with len() function?

Comment: No, not with the len() function. I've written a short [code on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/uCgMkyQ6) which should show how it could be done!

Comment: [link](https://pastebin.com/QBZLW79r) i got this error.

Comment: Oh yeah okay, replace the if statement with `if reaction.emoji == payload.emoji.name:` then

Comment: For example, three emojis are set. When someone cancels the emoji and puts it back and changes the emoji to three again, the bot sends the message again. i want it to send the message for one time after it reached the number 2 then the changes won't affect the message. how can i solve this problem?. i tried to this way "**if payload.emoji.name == '' and payload.emoji.name != '✔️'**:", because bot is adding '✔️' emoji when his job done. but it is same again. we have to make kind of if emoji adder is bot, dont send message maybe?

Comment: This isn't possible to be answered in comments. Try a litte by yourself, and if you don't succed ask another question with what you've tried so far :)

Comment: i'm already did sir :) but i didn't succed.